# Enabling ExtJS code completion with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: extjs, intellij-idea

How do I enable auto-complete/code completion feature of IntelliJ IDEA to work with ExtJS javascript library?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add ExtJS code assist to IntellijIDEA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212128/add-extjs-code-assist-to-intellijidea)

Answer (score 2):

This could probably be closed as a dup of this question:

[Add ExtJS code assist to IntellijIDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212128/add-extjs-code-assist-to-intellijidea)

The answer is here:

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/11/working-with-javascript-libraries-in-phpstorm-webstorm/

Answer (score 0):

do you have the extjs javascript files in your project?    I find that when I do Intellij is somewhat good at getting methods, but it doesn't always get all the available methods.  I thinks its just a gotcha of dynamic languages -- an IDE can't know all the methods available because some are available only at runtime...