# Add ExtJS code assist to IntellijIDEA

Tags: javascript, extjs, intellij-idea, code-completion, code-assist

how would I enable code-completion, docs-browsing in IntelliJIDEA 10 Ultimate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Refer to the blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2010/11/working-with-javascript-libraries-in-phpstorm-webstorm/) about working with JavaScript libraries. The same applies for IntelliJ IDEA product.